# boost bimap with second type as a list, flattening right map view

Tags: c++, boost, stl, bimap, boost-bimap

I recently saw that boost has a bidirectional map implementation named bimap.

My initial STL map was using the following 2 types:

- `int` as the key type
- `std::weak_ptr<void>` as the value type (let's call it `X`)

### Scenario 1

To create a bimap with these types, the declaration would be something like

`boost::bimap<int, boost::bimaps::set_of<X, std::owner_less<X>>>`

since `std::weak_ptr` needs an less operator (provided by `std::owner_less`) and is linked to the type with `boost::bimaps::set_of` to be usable(If I understood correctly).

### Scenario 2

I want my `int` type key from the map to point to multiple values of type `X`.

For a standard map, changing the value type from `X` to `std::list<X>` would be ok as in:
`std::map<int, std::list<X>>`

How could the bidirectional map be defined (or what can be used) so that right map view would be interpreted as a `map<X,int>` (flattening the lists of `X`), while the right one still being a `map<int,list<X>>`?

Comment: Off the top of head I'd suggest `bimap<int, multiset_of<X, std::owner_less<X> > >`, but I have no time to try it. I tend to avoid Bimap in favour of `boost::multi_index_container` as Bimap's interface manages to confuse me, and MultiIndex tends to lend more flexibility in the end. YMMV